# How to call servicestack social login API from Xamarin

Tags: facebook, authentication, xamarin, servicestack

I'm building an app that supports credentials authentication, facebook and google oauth on both Android and iOS.

My backend are written using ServiceStack.
For authentication using a browser we typically call /api/auth/facebook and ServiceStack handles the callbacks and exchange of information from the social provider such as facebook for a person logging in the first time and it also handles signing in a returning user via the same api endpoint.

When trying to connect to add support for facebook authentication or google in Xamarin app how do I call the ServiceStack endpoints to properly authenticate. How are the callbacks handled on mobile?

I'm a bit stuck with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [TechStacksAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacksAuth) repository which provides an example of how to use the [Xamarin.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) component to authenticate with a ServiceStack OAuth backend like Twitter.

Comment: Hi mythz, thanks for the reply. I had seen that example but I can not make it work with Facebook. The server throw an Unauthorized exception with every request. I could not find where is the error, if in server or facebook configuration

Comment: @JuanPablo You can submit an issue on the [TechStacksAuth project](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacksAuth/issues) requesting to expand the demo to add support for Facebook OAuth.

Comment: mythz, just right now i found that my Facebook redirecturl it was wrong. Now, is working like a charm. Thanks so much!